# Disable diffie-hellman or setting session key

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, openssh, diffie-hellman

Do you know if it is possible to disable Diffie-Hellman or set a fixed session key for openssh? Actually i want to analyze the traffic with WireShark and I need to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Options with SSH and Wireshark are really limited.  Wireshark [cannot decrypt SSH traffic](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSH) because it uses session keys derived from DH.  OpenSSH doesn't have a "fixed session key mode" because that would be really insecure and make it basically impossible to resolve the key oven an open channel.

you will need to put a MITM between your client and server, the record a pcap file of the decrypted traffic for wireshark to analyze.  [Ettercap](http://ettercap.github.com/ettercap/) is a good tool for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

what do you mean by "MITM between your client and server". It is not usefull because my MITM machine will record crypted data no?

Comment: no, your MITM machine will proxy a connection from the client to the server, forming sepearate encrypted connections with the client and the server, with the unencrypted data flowing through the MITM machine for storage and analysis.  so it looks like `[client] <-SSH1-> [MITM] <-SSH2-> [server]`